# How to post a UserEvent right after a self-defined mesh component is selected in Maya

Tags: c++, api, maya

Here's a Maya self-defined shape and I wanna do some thing right after the component of the shape is selected.

I registered a UserEvent and post it in the select function of shapeUI class, after the selectInfo.AddSelection call.

But the result is before I actually select the component of the shape, when I'm just hovering my mouse on the shape, the event was posted.

Any ideas where to put the postEvent call to make the event posted right after the actual selection is made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MEventMessage and addcallback on selection and then filter the message based on your nodeType. I have a answer posted similer kind of question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090392/how-to-get-from-maya-event-of-a-change-highlight-objects-in-the-scene/32102248#32102248) Although it is actually in python but you will be able to adjust according to your need in cpp. Thre are few examples in api docs also [api doc link](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_event_message_html). hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I finally choose to use scriptJob, which do the same thing, add a callback to selectionchange event.

Comment: But it's not so good, if I can get the self defined event work, I can then remove the filtering code and make the logic neat. Anyway, it works now. Thank you.